# Why cannot assign value to non-const reference?

Tags: c++

Why these definitions are all ok:

```
int func(int p=255) {
    return p;
}


int func1(const int &p=255) {
    return p;
}
```

but this definition:

```
int func2(int &p=255) {
    return p;
}
```

leads to compile error ?

What is the logic behind it ?

Comment: Because numeric literals aren't modifiable?

Comment: Why don't you add the compiler error message, for completeness?

Answer (score 3):

Taking arguments by reference means, you dont work with your local copy of the variable, but with a variable already defined in the scope of the calling function.

While your first example makes sense (you have a local variable p that you can fill with a default value) the second example is a bit more tricky: Usually when using references you expect the variable to have an address, since you want to modify it. For const-refernces, the compiler will still allow you to pass a literal, even if something like "reference to a literal" makes no sense at all.

In the third case the compiler expects you to modify p. But what part of the memory should this modification affect? "255" has no address - therefore it cant be used as a reference.

If you want to have a more detailed explanation, you should probably look for keywords like "rvalue" and "lvalue".

Answer (score 2):

The attempted function definition

```
auto func2( int& p = 255 )
    -> int
{ return p; }
```

… fails because you can't bind an rvalue to a reference to non-`const`. Basically that rule is because a simple value like `255` isn't modifiable. While the reference can be used to modify.

---

One simple solution is to express the default as a separate overload:

```
auto func2( int& p )
    -> int
{ return p; }

auto func2()
    -> int
{
    int scratchpad = 255;
    return func2( scratchpad );
}
```

Comment: Underrated response! The overload does exactly what one might possibly want to achieve with an optional non-const pass-by-reference!

Answer (score 2):

A non-const reference must be bound to lvalue (i.e. its address could be got). `255` (i.e. an int literal) is not a lvalue, so `int &p=255` fails.

A const reference could be bound to rvalue, and for this case, a temporary `int` will be created and initialized from `255`. The temporary `int`'s lifetime will be the same as the const reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
int func(int p=255) {
    return p;
}
```

`p` here is copied by value, and it is defined to exist in the scope of `func`.

```
int func2(int &p) {
    return p;
}
// e.g. use:
int value = 10;
func2(value);  // func2 *could* modify value because it is passed by non-const reference
```

In this case the compiler here expects `p` to have a name somewhere in memory (i.e. lvalue), so it can possibly write to it within `func2`.  Passing by non-const reference allows you to modify the variable used in the function call.  Since `p` must belong to **someone else** somewhere since it can be modified, you can't assign a default value to it.

But what about the const-reference case?  Here, the compiler is smart enough to know that `p` can never be written to since it is const, so it doesn't need to have a name in memory to write to.  In cases of a literal being passed (e.g. 255), it (behind the scenes) essentially creates a temporary and passes that temporary variable to the function.

```
int func1(const int &p=255) {
    return p;
}

func1(10);

// Behind the scenes, the compiler creates something along these lines
// since it can never be modified.
const int some_temporary = 10;
func1(some_temporary);
```